# 1324- undefined CURSOR in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
begin
    declare  i integer;
    declare cur cursor for select ecmtwork.mttotalline from ectmwork;
    OPEN cur;
    repeat
        fetch cut into i;
        until i =  468;       
    end repeat;
    close cur;
end;
```

I try to run this procedure,
mysql show error message('1324-Undefined CURSOR in mysql), 
anybody please tell solution, am using mysql server 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got the name of the cursor wrong in line6.
i.e the line

```
fetch cut into i;
```

should be

```
fetch cur into i;
```

Answer (score 0):

your program should be

```
   begin
declare  i integer;
declare cur cursor for select ecmtwork.mttotalline from ectmwork;
OPEN cur;
repeat
    fetch cur into i;
    until i =  468;       
end repeat;
close cur;
  end;
```